# {"error_type": "OAuthException", "code": 400, "error_message": "Invalid redirect_uri"}

Tags: php, instagram

Firstly, this is my Instagram URL after the login:

```
https://www.instagram.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=$MYCLİENTİD&redirect_uri=https://localhost:4000/İnstagram/Insta.php/&response_type=code&scope=user_profile,user_media
```

And this is the error that page shows me:

> {"error_type": "OAuthException", "code": 400, "error_message": "Invalid redirect_uri"}

When I try to get user token from Instagram, I get that error.
I've tried to change the `redirect_uri=(Valid OAuth Redirect URIs)`, but the error is the same as before.

Comment: Maybe the redirect URI cannot be localhost

Comment: you need to url_encode the redirect_uri before

Comment: is that a maybe or it cn not ? because ı tried to send google and it gives same error. (ı changed it in url and in api settings in dev.facebook) AND ı make url_encode too

Comment: How can i use localhost redirect_uri for Instagram app for testing purpose? It also gives me same error. Need help

Answer (score 7):

I could not find this documented anywhere, but through trial and error, I found that the redirect_uri had to:

1. Use https
2. Be publicly accessible (e.g. localhost and specifying a port number won't work)
3. Not include parameters (I found they were getting stripped out, which would cause a redirect_uri mismatch when I later requested an access token)

Comment: Additionally, you have to wait sometimes up to 5 minutes after saving the redirect_url in Facebook

Comment: works with localhost

Answer (score 6):

Actually, for me, it was because my URI was not exactly the same as requested by the app. I forgot to add "/" at the end.

Comment: `https://localhost:8080/` work for me , `https://localhost:8080` not work

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem and I solved it as following:
I first went here:
(*remember to change your instagram app id in the below URL*)
https://developers.facebook.com/apps/your_instagram_app_id/instagram-basic-display/basic-display/

Then I set my `Client OAuth Settings`, `Deauthorize` and `Data Deletion Requests` as "https://localhost:3000/".

That worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Go to https://developers.facebook.com/apps/APP_ID/instagram-basic-display/basic-display/ -> `Client OAuth Settings` and put there not just https://localhost:5000, but exact authentication endpoint used in your application (https://localhost:5000/auth or else)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it does work with localhost, but it is very tedious.

- First, you need to have https enabled (which from what I can see from your request you seem to have).
- [I don't know if this is mandatory] you need to create a test app* from your main app (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/development/build-and-test/test-apps/)
- Set the redirect OAuth URI to something like `https://localhost:4000/auth/` and update also all other URIs in `.../instagram-basic-display/basic-display/` settings.
- Finally, don't forget to use the client-id(or app-id) of the test app in your request, which is different than your parent app

I wish you good luck ;)

***IMPORTANT**: app-id and app-secret are different in test app!

Answer (score 0):

As per documentation

> Construct the Authorization Window URL below, replacing {app-id} with
> your Instagram app’s ID (from the App Dashboard > Products > Instagram
>
> > Basic Display > Instagram App ID field) and {redirect-uri} with your website URL that you provided in Step 2 ("Valid OAuth Redirect URIs").
> > The URL must be exactly the same.

Syntax & Example as below

```
https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=<instagram_app_id>&redirect_uri=<my-website>&scope=user_profile,user_media&response_type=code

https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=00000123&redirect_uri=https://aashutosh-kumar.herokuapp.com/&scope=user_profile,user_media&response_type=code
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check that redirect uri you are passig through API must match exactly with the redirect uri mentioned in Meta developer settings.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).